# Minimal length cycle containing an edge

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I need a polynomial algorithm that finds the minimal length cycle in a directed graph containing a specific edge (u,v), or prove that this is NP-hard.
All edges weigh the same.

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote?         We are humans. Many people can miss that.      Is it better if this question is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BFS to find a shortest path $v\rightsquigarrow u$, and then $u\rightarrow v \rightsquigarrow u$ is the cycle you want. Try to prove for yourself and see why this works!